# Map :w (save) and a call for a .sh file to F2 in VIM

Tags: vim

I'd like to map F2 in VIM so that it first saves the file with `:w` and then calls a script `/home/user/proj/script.sh` that will upload the changed files to the server.
I already tried

```
:map F2 :w<cr>|:! /home/user/proj/script.sh
```

but that doesn't work.

Please tell my why this isn't working and help me to get this working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `:noremap <F2> :<c-u>update <bar> !/home/user/proj/script.sh<cr>`.

*`noremap` vs. `map`*

This creates a non-recursive mapping. See [Wikia - Mappings keys in Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29#Nested_.28recursive.29_maps)

I just assumed this, because it's what people want most of the time. :-)

*`update` vs. `write`*

Only save the file if there were actual changes. See: `:help :update`.

*`<bar>` vs. `|`*

`:help map_bar`

*`<c-u>`?*

You used a generic mapping, instead of one for a certain mode, like `nmap` for normal mode mappings. Thus the mapping could also be triggered in visual mode. If you select something in visual mode and hit `:`, you'll see the commandline is prefixed with a range. But you don't want that in your case and `<c-u>` clears the commandline.

*`<cr>` at the end?*

Your mapping drops into the commandline mode and inserts 2 things separated by `<bar>`. Afterwards it has to execute what it has written, thus you need to append a `<cr>`.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Could you explain why you used "noremap" instead of map, <c-u>update instead of w, <bar> instead of | and the <cr> at the end of the line? I'd honour it with an additional upvote (in addition to the accept for which I have to wait another 2 minutes) ;)

Comment: Ah, of course, but I'll edit my answer so it's more readable!